# Create instance of class by string, but take implicit conversions into account - C# Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor, implicit-conversion

I am in a situation where I need to create an object instance given a Type (as a string), and an array of constructor arguments.

This is how I achieve that:

```
public object Create(string Name, params object[] Args)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(Name), Args);
}
```

This works fine in most cases, but there is a problem with it; it doesn't take implicit conversions into account.

---

Let me explain what I mean, say we have a simple class with an implicit conversion to int defined

```
public class ImplicitTest
{
    public double Val { get; set; }

    public ImplicitTest(double Val)
    {
        this.Val = Val;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(ImplicitTest d)
    {
        return (int)d.Val;
    }
}
```

and we have a class that uses an int as it's constructor's parameter

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Val { get; set; }        

    public TestClass(int Val)
    {
        this.Val = Val;
    }
}
```

Now say we want to make an instance of TestClass, we can do:
`new TestClass(5)`. In this case, we use the exact parameter type, that the constructor specifies (int). However we can also create an instance of the class using our ImplicitTest class, as such: `new TestClass(new ImplicitTest(5.1))`. This works, because the parameter is implicitly converted from ImplicitTest to int. Activator.CreateInstance() however does not do this.

---

We can use our `Create(string Name, params object[] Args)` method from before to make an instance of TestClass as such: `Create("ThisNamespace.TestClass", 5)`, this works.
The problem I am experiencing is that trying to use implicit conversions does not work, therefore this snippet throws an error: `Create("ThisNamespace.TestClass", new ImplicitTest(5.1))`

I have absolutely no idea how take this into account, but it is important for my use case. Maybe there is some parameter of the Activator.CreateInstance() function I am missing, or maybe there is a completely different method I can use to achieve my goal? I have not been able to find any answers.

---

## TL;DR

```
//Valid
new TestClass(5);

//Valid
new TestClass(new ImplicitTest(5.1));

//Valid
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("ThisNamespace.TestClass"), 5); 

//Invalid, throws System.MissingMethodException
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("ThisNamespace.TestClass"), new ImplicitTest(5.1));
```

Why?

Comment: Similar thread that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932208/activator-createinstance-not-working-for-implicit-cast-scenario

Comment: Because `implicit operator int` is `static`, so it doesn't override any method of `object` class. And with `Activator.CreateInstance` the `Args` you pass are `object`s

Comment: It is possible to leverage the dynamic infrastructure of .NET . The `Microsoft.CSharp` assembly has the C# "rules" for overload selection. See https://ideone.com/UkGm4E . I'm not expert enough to translate it to a "generic" working method (dynamic isn't my field of C#)

Comment: @xanatos This actually seems pretty promising, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Implicit type conversion is a feature of the C# compiler, not the CLR.

Therefore, if you are willing to use Reflection, you'll have to achieve it manually.

Comment: I'll add that this is a task of the `Binder` class (used in `ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, ...`). Sadly there is no `CSharpBinder` "around the internet"

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to implement IConvertible in your class?
You don't have to implement all methods,just the ones you need.
If yes,you can use something like the following.
(You can make it more generic so you don't have to search for specific constructor like I do now)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var theType = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication.TestClass");

            ConstructorInfo ctor = theType.GetConstructors()[0];
            var argumentType = ctor.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;

            object contructorArgument = new ImplicitTest(5.1);

            object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { Convert.ChangeType(contructorArgument, argumentType) });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int Val { get; set; }

        public TestClass(int Val)
        {
            this.Val = Val;
        }

    }

    public class ImplicitTest : IConvertible
    {
        public double Val { get; set; }

        public ImplicitTest(double Val)
        {
            this.Val = Val;
        }

        public static implicit operator int(ImplicitTest d)
        {
            return (int)d.Val;
        }

        public int ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return (int)this;
        }

        //Other methods of IConvertible
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in the dynamic part of C#, but this seems to work correctly:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder; // Requires reference to Microsoft.CSharp

public class ImplicitTest
{
    public double Val { get; set; }

    public ImplicitTest(double val)
    {
        this.Val = val;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(ImplicitTest d)
    {
        return (int)d.Val;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public int Val { get; set; }

    public TestClass(int val = 5)
    {
        this.Val = val;
    }

    public TestClass(int val1, int val2)
    {
        this.Val = val1 + val2;
    }

    public TestClass(int val1, int val2, int val3, int val4, int val5, int val6, int val7, int val8, int val9, int val10, int val11, int val12, int val13, int val14)
    {
        this.Val = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6 + val7 + val8 + val9 + val10 + val11 + val12 + val13 + val14;
    }
}

public static class DynamicFactory
{
    private static readonly CallSiteBinder callsiteBinder0 = Binder.InvokeConstructor(
        CSharpBinderFlags.None,
        typeof(DynamicFactory),
        // It is OK to have too many arguments :-)
        new CSharpArgumentInfo[] 
        {
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null), // 0 parameters
        });

    private static readonly CallSiteBinder callsiteBinder = Binder.InvokeConstructor(
        CSharpBinderFlags.None,
        typeof(DynamicFactory),
        // It is OK to have too many arguments :-)
        // Note that this "feature" doesn't work correctly with Mono in the
        // case of 0 arguments
        new CSharpArgumentInfo[] 
        {
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null), // 0 parameters
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), // 1 parameter
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), // 2 parameters
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), 
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), 
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), 
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), // 14 parameters
        });

    // Quirk of Mono with 0 arguments. See callsiteBinder0
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object>> CallSite0 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder0);

    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object>> CallSite1 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object>> CallSite2 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object>> CallSite3 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite4 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite5 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite6 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite7 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite8 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite9 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite10 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite11 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite12 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite13 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);
    private static readonly CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>> CallSite14 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object>>.Create(callsiteBinder);

    public static object Create(string typeName, params object[] args)
    {
        return Create(Type.GetType(typeName), args);
    }

    public static object Create(Type type, params object[] args)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        }

        if (args == null)
        {
            args = new object[0];
        }

        object obj;

        switch (args.Length)
        {
            case 0:
                // Quirk of Mono with 0 arguments. See callsiteBinder0
                obj = CallSite0.Target(CallSite0, type);
                break;

            case 1:
                obj = CallSite1.Target(CallSite1, type, args[0]);
                break;

            case 2:
                obj = CallSite2.Target(CallSite2, type, args[0], args[1]);
                break;

            case 3:
                obj = CallSite3.Target(CallSite3, type, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
                break;

            case 4:
                obj = CallSite4.Target(CallSite4, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
                break;

            case 5:
                obj = CallSite5.Target(CallSite5, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]);
                break;

            case 6:
                obj = CallSite6.Target(CallSite6, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]);
                break;

            case 7:
                obj = CallSite7.Target(CallSite7, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6]);
                break;

            case 8:
                obj = CallSite8.Target(CallSite8, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7]);
                break;

            case 9:
                obj = CallSite9.Target(CallSite9, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8]);
                break;

            case 10:
                obj = CallSite10.Target(CallSite10, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9]);
                break;

            case 11:
                obj = CallSite11.Target(CallSite11, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9], args[10]);
                break;

            case 12:
                obj = CallSite12.Target(CallSite12, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9], args[10], args[11]);
                break;

            case 13:
                obj = CallSite13.Target(CallSite13, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9], args[10], args[11], args[12]);
                break;

            case 14:
                obj = CallSite14.Target(CallSite14, type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8], args[9], args[10], args[11], args[12], args[13]);
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Too many parameters");
        }

        return obj;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Type monoRuntime = Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime");

            if (monoRuntime != null)
            {
                System.Reflection.MethodInfo displayName = monoRuntime.GetMethod("GetDisplayName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

                if (displayName != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Mono version {0}", displayName.Invoke(null, null));
                }
            }

            TestClass tc0 = (TestClass)DynamicFactory.Create("TestClass");
            TestClass tc1 = (TestClass)DynamicFactory.Create("TestClass", new ImplicitTest(1.0));
            TestClass tc1b = (TestClass)DynamicFactory.Create("TestClass", 1);
            TestClass tc2 = (TestClass)DynamicFactory.Create("TestClass", new ImplicitTest(1.0), new ImplicitTest(2.0));
            TestClass tc14 = (TestClass)DynamicFactory.Create("TestClass", Enumerable.Range(0, 14).Select(x => new ImplicitTest((double)x)).ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine(tc0.Val);
            Console.WriteLine(tc1.Val);
            Console.WriteLine(tc1b.Val);
            Console.WriteLine(tc2.Val);
            Console.WriteLine(tc14.Val);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

It leverages the "dynamic" part of .NET . It uses the *Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder* that "knows" the binding rules of C#. As someone else noted, user-defined implicit and explicit casts are something of C#, not of the .NET, so you need a binder that "knows" about them. The perfect solution would be to have subclass of the `System.Reflection.Binder` class that "knows" of C# rules. Then you could pass it to the `Type.GetConstructor` and live happy. Sadly there is no implementation like that.

Note that sadly the delegate is stored in a generic subclass of `CallSite`, `CallSite<T>`, with `T` being the delegate type. For this reason the big `switch` instruction.

Ideone of the code: https://ideone.com/NoQ67H . Note that there is quirk in Mono, so 0 parameter constructors have special handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the Expressions framework, here is an example that should do the "trick":

```
class Program
{
    static object Create(string Name, params object[] Args)
    {
        Type theType = Type.GetType(Name);
        object toReturn = null;
        // Code wrote quickly, I just try to call all the type constructors...
        foreach (var constructor in Type.GetType(Name).GetConstructors())
        {
            try
            {
                string paramPrefix = "p";
                int pIdx = 0;
                var expParamsConsts = new List<Expression>();
                var ctrParams = constructor.GetParameters();
                for (int i = 0; i < constructor.GetParameters().Length; i++)
                {
                    var param = ctrParams[i];
                    var tmpParam = Expression.Variable(param.ParameterType, paramPrefix + pIdx++);
                    var expConst = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(Args[i]), param.ParameterType);
                    expParamsConsts.Add(expConst);
                }
                // new Type(...);
                var expConstructor = Expression.New(constructor, expParamsConsts);
                // return new Type(...);
                var expLblRetTarget = Expression.Label(theType);
                var expReturn = Expression.Return(expLblRetTarget, expConstructor, theType);
                var expLblRet = Expression.Label(expLblRetTarget, Expression.Default(theType));
                // { return new Type(...); }
                var expBlock = Expression.Block(expReturn, expLblRet);
                // Build the expression and run it
                var expFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic>>(expBlock);
                toReturn = expFunc.Compile().Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tmpTestClass = Create(TYPE_NAME, 5);
        tmpTestClass = Create(TYPE_NAME, new ImplicitTest(5.1));
    }
}

public class ImplicitTest
{
    public double Val { get; set; }

    public ImplicitTest(double Val)
    {
        this.Val = Val;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(ImplicitTest d)
    {
        return (int)d.Val;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public int Val { get; set; }

    public TestClass(int Val)
    {
        this.Val = Val;
    }
}
```

Probably there are quicker way to do so, but I'm not very expert in Expressions...

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to see you're not using `Expression`s very often - most people simply build a tree of expressions, rather than storing all the intermediates in locals :D It's obvious you're not very affected by functional programming yet. In any case, this is a great solution for pretty much any time you need reflection, while also exploiting what's usually handled by the compiler (e.g. boxing, implicit conversions, overload resolution...). Although I'd only really use this when there's only one constructor to "choose" from, since picking the right constructor like this is kind of ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, in this case I decided to use intermediate variables because it seemed to me more readable

Comment: Yeah, that comes with the "not used to functional programming". Try playing around with FP a bit, and you'll be a lot more comfortable with it. Which is kind of important when C# is getting more and more functional over time (delegates, expression trees, LINQ, ...). The key point is that pure functions allow you to reason about the individual function calls in isolation, so "skipping" the intermediates doesn't necessarily make readability worse. But really, this is just a stylistic matter, nothing too important. FP is a great tool for your toolset, though :)

Comment: @Luaan *Yeah, it's easy to see you're not using Expressions very often* I write many `Expression`s and I do store everything in a separate variable. The alternative is to have lines of code that go from the left of my table to the right of the table :-)

Comment: @xanatos Well, the typical solution to that is to use multi-line expressions :) But yeah, it's a stylistical choice. I see it far often with programmers who started influenced with FP rather than old-school imperative programmers. It probably helps that a functional program is *all* just a single expression (in theory) - using intermediates just looks like an attempt to keep the code looking imperative, even though it isn't. Do you also store partial (but not dynamic) LINQ queries in locals? Or do you use the "fluent syntax"? It's basically equivalent.

Comment: @Luaan I tend to go to a new line just before the dot call... `(newline).Where(...)(newline).Select` and so on.

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, that's exactly what I do (unless it's a very short query). And I use the same approach with expression trees, you just have parentheses instead of the `.`, basically. There's plenty of reasons why functional languages avoid the parentheses around arguments - if you consider how the code would look without the dots and parentheses, you'll see that they end up looking basically the same.